# FETCH API_CURSOR causing open transaction in tempDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

A select statement run from Oracle 11gR1 to SQL Server 2005 using Gateway leaves an open transaction in tempdb. The user is a datareader in Database XYZ. Not sure why the open tran is in tempDB when the statement run is SELECT.

Any one had seen this issue before ?

Thanks in advance
sekhar

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's spilling memory to the tempdb database because it's a large select statement.  What's the size of the recordset which is being returned?